# d3.js right align nested bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with [this d3.js example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663)  and am looking to change the charts entire orientation to go instead from right to left.

I was able to reverse the x-axis scale:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([width, 0]);
```

and the placement of the y axis:

```
svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis")
               .attr("transform", "translate("+width+", 0)")
               .append("line").attr("y1", "100%");
```

I believe I have to set the transform on each bar to the chart width - the bar width however applying ANY transform to the containing `g` has no effect.

```
 function bar(d) {
    var bar = svg.insert("g", ".y.axis")
                 .attr("class", "enter")
                 .attr("transform", "translate(0,5)")
                 .selectAll("g")
                 .data(d.children)
                 .enter().append("g");
  //DOESNT WORK
  bar.attr("transform", function(n){ return "translate("+ (width - x(n.value)) +", 0)"; })  
     .style("cursor", function(d) { return !d.children ? null : "pointer"; })
     .on("click", down);

  bar.append("text")....

  bar.append("rect")....

  return bar;
}
```

No transform is set on `bar` even if I just do a test with a fixed value, the result is translate(0,0) in the resulting page.

Why doesnt the transform not get applied here and is this even the correct way to make the bars right align? I also need the text to be on the right side of the bar instead of on the left and it seems that changing the order of appending makes no difference in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this particular example is that the code is a bit confusing -- the positions of the `rect` elements are set in various non-obvious places. In particular, the transform you are setting is overwritten immediately by other code.

I've modified the example to do what you want [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/9173284). The key points are that I'm moving the `g` element containing all bars to the right

```
var bar = svg.insert("g", ".y.axis")
  .attr("class", "enter")
  .attr("transform", "translate("+width+",5)")
.selectAll("g")
// etc
```

and setting the `x` position of the `rect` elements to be their negative width

```
bar.append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return width-x(d.value); })
  .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
  .attr("height", barHeight);
```

The `x` position needs to be set in a few other places in the code in this way -- there're almost certainly more elegant ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks, it's not quite the same effect since the transition still comes from the right side it jumps off the chart but I'll just have someone fix that later. Much appreciated :)

Comment: hey Lars the correct calc is attr("x", function(d) { return x.scale(d.value) - width; }.attr("width", function(d) { return width - x(d.value); }) otherwise the values are inverted (ie 30 becomes "30 away from max")

Comment: So this depends on how you translate the container element -- at least in the modified example everything should be working correctly, no?

Comment: From an eye's glance, yes. At the data level, not quite. Notice how the "vis" bar is the smallest in one example and the largest in the other. The calc in my comment will reverse it back. I do hope someone find that more elegant way and posts here :)

Comment: My apologies -- you're absolutely right. I'll update the answer.